# Reading, editing, then saving over a text(.txt) file as a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to Python so I could use a lot of help here! My goal is to take an article and filter out all of the trash words then eventually import them to excel so I can do some text analysis. As it stands, the articles are too long to copy into a single cell due to size limitations. I have the following code:

```
article = open(filename, 'w')

letters_only = re.sub("[^a-zA-Z]",  # Search for all non-letters
                          " ",          # Replace all non-letters with spaces
                          str(article))

stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english')) 

# Tokenize the article: tokens
tokens = word_tokenize(letters_only)

# Convert the tokens into lowercase: lower_tokens
lower_tokens = [t.lower() for t in tokens]

# Retain alphabetic words: alpha_only
alpha_only = [t for t in lower_tokens if t.isalpha()]

filtered_sentence = [w for w in alpha_only if not w in stop_words] 

filtered_sentence = [] 

for w in alpha_only: 
    if w not in stop_words: 
        filtered_sentence.append(w)

article.write(str(filtered_sentence))
```

The problem I am having is that when I try to write the file, the code basically deletes all of the text and writes over it with nothing. If there is an easier way of just prepping a file for machine learning and/or just stripping a file of stop_words and saving over it, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Why are you doing analysis in Excel when you already have all the data in Python?

Comment: Is that all of your code? I don't see you reading the file anywhere.

Comment: @MadPhysicist. I have 190 files I need to clean and add to their respective rows in excel. Like I said, I'm brand new to python.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provided all your code, as read is not mentioned anywhere, in order to help you, we need to have more context. I will still try to help you with what you provided.

If you load your article from the web, I advise you to keep it as a plain string (aka. not saving it in a file), clean it from what you don't want, then save it.

Otherwise, if you load it from a file, you may prefer to save the cleaned article in another file, then remove the original one. It prevents from losing data.

Here, your code remove the content of the file due to the w flag, and prints nothing on it

> 'w'  -> Truncate file to zero length or create text file for writing.
>            The stream is positioned at the beginning of the file.

Also, filtered_sentence is a list of strings, you can't convert it in a single one like that

```
article.write(str(filtered_sentence))
```

you should do the following

```
article.write(" ".join(filtered_sentence))
```

You may consider use the with statement, which close the file automatically, which you don't seems to do.

```
with open(filename, 'w') as article:
    article.write(" ".join(filtered_sentence))
```

Comment: Thanks for attempting to help! Read was on the second line, but I copied from a different version that didn't work. I'm getting different errors each time I try something new. I tried the: with open(filename, 'w') as article:
    article.write(" ".join(filtered_sentence)) and it says that filtered_sentences aren't defined. I have to download the articles as pdfs (they aren't available in any other format). I then converted them to txt. So, rather than overwriting, what's the best way of saving them as a new text file in the same folder? Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: @jjsimpson What do you use for converting pdf to text?

Comment: I used PyPDF2 to convert it.

Answer (score 0):

As you added more context in the comments of my previous answer, I prefer to rewrite all of it.

```
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from textract import process
import urllib2, os, re

response = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.website.com/file.pdf') #Request file from interet
tmp_path = 'tmp_path/file.pdf'

with open(tmp_path, 'wb') as tmp_file: #Open the pdf file
    tmp_file.write(response.read()) #Write the request content (aka the pdf file data)

text = process(tmp_path) #Extract text from pdf
text = re.sub("[^a-zA-Z]", " ", text) #Remove all non alphabetical words

os.remove(tmp_path) #Remove the temp pdf file

words = word_tokenize(text)

#words = [t.lower() for t in lower_tokens if t.isalpha()]
#Is the above line useful as you removed all non alphanumerical character at line 13 ?
stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))
filtered_sentence = [w for w in words if w not in stop_words]

with open("path/to/your/article.txt", 'w') as article: #Open destination file
    article.write(" ".join(filtered_sentence)) #Write all the words separated by a space
```

/!\ I don't have any python environment to test it (Smartphones... Meh.), but it should work fine. If any error occurs please report it, I will correct it.

Comment: Thanks again. I appreciate your help and I don't want to bother you anymore since I'm getting a problem with the code you provided. When I try to import textract it tells me that there is no module for textract. When I install textract, it gives and error "command setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in path. I haven't had any problems using pip install, but it seems to have a problem with textract.

Comment: @jjsimpson Use PyPDF2 instead then, it should be the same

Comment: @jjsimpson Please note that the extractText function from this library have known issues with some PDF (especially if it is formatted in a complicated way, or have pictures).

Comment: @jjsimpson It seems textract have some installation problems with windows10 and some versions of python.
Which one do you use? It is x64?
Nethertheless, it may work using easy_install instead of pip:
`py -m easy_install textract`

Comment: I was able to troubleshoot my way through textract, but I still get the following error copying and pasting the code provided: TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes. Another problem from using the webbrower approach is that I am having to access the articles via university library, which I have to login to (I'm not sure if that matters). Also, I'm not quite sure what to put in tmp_path = 'tmp_path/.pdf'. Just leave this alone or put in the file path where I want the file to go?

Comment: @jjsimpson Please provide the entire error log, "TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes." Only teach me about the type of error, not where it occured.
Yes, put the file path where you want the file to be save.
The login problem may be a problem, you still can avoid this part and download it by yourself, then just store the path where you saved it in tmp_path

Comment: Is there any way I can repay you for helping me out? Here is the error code: File "C:\Users\simps\OneDrive\Python\test.py", line 15, in <module>
    tmp_file.write(response.read()) #Write the request content (aka the pdf file data)
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes

Comment: Stack Overflow have reputation system in order to thanks user for helping you, you can accept an answer if you feel it answered your question, or upvote the useful comments/answers.Thanks for providing the error, I modified the code, I think it comes from two problems : I forgot to import re, and the file wasn't open in binary mode